# What to cast column to in order to have csv export not show scientific notation?

Tags: sql, csv, casting, presto

Currently, when I export the results of my query (to .csv) the SKU column gets converted to scientific notation.  Is there anything I can cast my SKU column to in order to have it come out as the full string?  Some SKUs are all numbers, some are all letters, and some are numbers and letters.  A lot of the casts I've tried result in this type of error: Cannot cast '190198047908' to INT.

Comment: What's the type of your SKU column? If it's a VARCHAR (since it may contain letters), you should be able to output it verbatim and no automatic conversion should happen. Can you show your query and how you're exporting it to CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Often `numeric` works where `int` does not:

```
select cast(col as numeric(38, 0))
```

I don't know if there are decimal points, but the conversion to `int` suggests that you do not care about any digits to the right of the decimal point.